# Problem with image in bootstrap navbar-brand

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I have one picture (logo) from directory img and I cannot see image in logo:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-lg">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="../img/villa-ahar-web-logo1.png" alt="sdsd"  height="60" width="258"/>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <a class="nav-link active"href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Courses</a>
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">About</a>
    </div>
    <form>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <button class="btn" type="button">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

I am sure path is good.

Thanks and regards

Pietro

Comment: Hi Pietro, please describe your problem a bit further. Are there any errors showing up in your developers console? As of right now, theres no way we can reproduce your exact case as neither you delivered a runnable snippet nor anything else which could clue us of whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<img>` path to this:

```
<img src="../../img/villa-ahar-web-logo1.png" alt="sdsd"  height="60" width="258"/>
```